# My solution on series of functions: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Study the punctual, absolute and uniform convergence of the following series of functions:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$$

I have done this. Is it correct?

**1. Pointwise Convergence**:

For each fixed $x$, we need to check if the sequence of functions converges. Let's denote the $n$-th term of the series as $f_n(x)$:
$$f_n(x) = \left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$$

Since the range of $\arcsin$ is between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the term inside the $\arcsin$ function tends to infinity as $x$ approaches either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, we can see that the series is defined only for $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$.

**2. Absolute Convergence:**

To test absolute convergence, we need to consider the absolute value of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n\right|$$

Since $\left|\arcsin(y)\right| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $y$, we have:
$$\left|\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n\right| \leq \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$$

So, the series converges absolutely for all $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$ because it's dominated by a convergent geometric series.

**3. Uniform Convergence**:

To check uniform convergence, we need to see if the series converges uniformly on any given interval. However, since the series is not defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can't talk about uniform convergence over the entire real line.

Instead, we can consider intervals $[-a, -1]$ and $[1, a]$ for some $a > 1$. In these intervals, the series converges pointwise, and we've shown it converges absolutely. However, uniform convergence cannot be guaranteed as the behavior may differ for different values of $x$.

So, to summarize:

- The series converges pointwise for $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$.
- It converges absolutely in the same interval.
- Uniform convergence cannot be asserted over the entire real line, but it may hold in smaller intervals such as $[-a, -1]$ and $[1, a]$ for $a > 1$.

**Correct version: follow up.**

**1. Pointwise Convergence:**

For each fixed $x$, we need to check if the sequence of functions converges. Let $$f_n(x) = \left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n$$

The domain of the arcsine function is $[-1, 1]$, but since we're considering $\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)$, the function is defined only when $\frac{2x^2-1}{x}$ lies within $[-1, 1]$, which gives $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$.

For $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$, the series converges pointwise.

To test absolute convergence, we consider the absolute value of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n\right|$$

Since the range of $\arcsin$ is $[-1, 1]$, we have:

$$\left|\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n\right| \leq 1$$

So, the series converges absolutely for all $x \in]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$.

To test uniform convergence, we'll consider intervals of the form $[-a, -1]$and $[1, a]$ for $a > 1$. Within these intervals, the series converges pointwise and absolutely, but uniform convergence cannot be guaranteed as the behavior may differ for different values of $x$.

Hence I can write that the series converges pointwise for $x \in ]-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty[$. It converges absolutely for the same interval.
The uniform convergence cannot be guaranteed over the entire real line, but it may hold in smaller intervals such as $[-a, -1]$ and $[1, a]$ for $a$ real with $a > 1$.

Comment: `Sum[ArcSin[(2 x^2 - 1)/x]^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]` Mathematica code shows the sum result is $-\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x^2-1}{x}\right)}{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x^2-1}{x}\right)-1}$    


( because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n =\frac{1}{1-x}$? )

Comment: @138Aspen I don't use Mathematica, and I don't understand where the sum comes from.

Comment: $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$ is convergent? Sorry if I’m missing something

Comment: @AnthonyML Sorry I have done a wrong. Now I correct it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. For example, for $x=1$ one gets $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\arcsin(1))^n=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)^n=\infty$.

Notice that the series is actually geometric, and will converge iff the ratio is smaller than $1$ in modulus.

That will happen when $$\left|\arcsin\left(\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right|<1\iff \left|\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x}\right|<\sin(1)\iff \\\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x}<\sin(1), \space x\geq0, \text{ or } \dfrac{2x^2-1}{-x}<\sin(1), \space x<0 $$

Solving this inequalities (Multiplying by $x$ or $-x$ respectively, one gets quadratic equations), one obtains that the pointwise convergence is only attained at  (approximated values) $(-0.948,-0.527)\cup (0.527, 0.948)$.

Absolute convergence is also achieved in that set, since for the values there (why?)$$ \left|\arcsin\left(\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right|=\pm\arcsin\left(\left|\dfrac{2x^2-1}{x}\right|\right)$$ and the set is symmetric respect to the origin.

Uniform convergence is only achieved in compact subsets, as usually happens with geometric series (when $x$ approaches the extremes of the intervals, the ratio approaches $\pm 1$).

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[m_] := AsymptoticSum[
  ArcSin[(2 x^2 - 1)/x]^n, {n, 1, Infinity}, {x, Sqrt[1/2], m}]
f[4]
```

Mathematica code shows that:

$$
\text{For } x \text{ centered at }\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \text{, }
\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n
\sim 
4 \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) + \left(16-2 \sqrt{2}\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2
-\frac{4}{3} \left(12 \sqrt{2}-59\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3
-\frac{4}{3}  \left(87 \sqrt{2}-286\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4
\cdots
$$

---

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[m_] := AsymptoticSum[
  ArcSin[(2 x^2 - 1)/x]^n, {n, 1, Infinity}, {x, -Sqrt[1/2], m}]
f[4]
```

Mathematica code shows that:

$$
\text{For } x \text{ centered at }-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \text{, }
\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{2x^2-1}{x}\right)\right]^n
\sim 
+4 \left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
+\left(2 \sqrt{2}+16\right) \left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2
+\frac{4}{3} \left(12 \sqrt{2}+59\right) \left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^3
+\frac{4}{3} \left(87 \sqrt{2} +286\right) \left(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4
\cdots
$$